# Let user change time and date with Moment or other library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, time, momentjs

- I am working on a Electron react app for a device.
- On the device it displays the current time and date.
- admins can change the timezone and/or edit the current Date and Time.
- Timezones are easy with moment-timezone.
- I have a simple 10 second interval to update the time using `moment().tz("timZOne").format(MM/DD/YYY) etc..`
- What I don't understand is how I would go about letting a user change the time and date and have the clock (moment) update from that time forward.
- I don't think this is possible with moment.js
- Is this something that needs to be handled by the Back-End or can I handle this from the Front-End

TLDR:

- currentTime from moment() `10:30AM` --updated every ten seconds
- user Changes currentTime to `9:30am` --start keeping time from 9:30AM onwards
- same Idea with Dates -- if the user changes the currentDate I want my application to start keeping track of time and date from the users inputted date or time.
- Not looking for help with time zones. I want the functionality stated above. Users can already change time zones flawlessly.

Comment: Momentjs lets you [Changing Time Source](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/customization/now/), maybe this feature can help achieving your goals.

Comment: Surprised I never saw this. Got it working pretty well but now I am having issues with timeZones after a user sets the date. Thank you!